# Is it possible to change the Access data source to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ms-access

I'm currently managing a "db" in Access (meh). A complex structure of masks and VBA scripts was built over this "db".

What I'd like to do is change the Access datasource from Access itself to SQL Server. I've already upsized and imported the whole data. In this way the users keep managing the system using the old Access masks & scripts but the data is inside SQL Server.

Is this possible? Or do I have to create the whole managing structure from scratch?

My problem is that more than one "client" have to manage the data simultaneously, that's why I'm searching for the magic "edit data source" button. The upsize seems to link a single instance of Access to the new data source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

When you "upsize", Access creates "linked tables".
The queries and forms on top of this don't know any difference

Some links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/184406/27535 (SO)
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2279654/en-us (MS KB)

Edit:

You'll need to deploy a new mdb/accdb to each client, along with a DSN (Control Panel, Admin tools, "Data Sources (ODBC)")

Comment: So the upsize alters the data source of the single Access file?
My problem is that more than one "client" have to manage the data simultaneously, that's why I'm searching for the magic "edit data source" button. I'll edit also the main questione to clarify.